# How to translate from C# to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-conversion

For a project written in VB.net I want to use the `PropertyChangeNotifier` class from [this article](https://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/), at least I'd like to try if it can help.

Since the original class is written in C# I tried to translate this class to VB.net, but one function I can'T get to compile and I don't know why, maybe you can help.

The original function in C# is:

```
private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyChangeNotifier notifier = (PropertyChangeNotifier)d;
    if (notifier.ValueChanged != null)
        notifier.ValueChanged(notifier, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

My (slightly altered) translation (and the automatic translation of several web sites) is:

```
Private Shared Sub OnPropertyChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim notifier As PropertyChangeNotifier

    notifier = TryCast(d, PropertyChangeNotifier)
    If (notifier Is Nothing) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    RaiseEvent notifier.ValueChanged(notifier, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

If I remove the `RaiseEvent` the compiler tells me, that `ValueChanged` is an event and can't be called directly, I should use `RaiseEvent`. But when I use `RaiseEvent` the compiler tells me

> 'notifier' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

But as ylou can see `notifier` is declared a few lines up.

Comment: Simply change `RaiseEvent notifier.ValueChanged(notifier, EventArgs.Empty)` to `RaiseEvent ValueChanged(notifier, EventArgs.Empty)`

Comment: I'm in a static function and the `ValueChanged` event is a non static event of the `PropertyChangeNotifier` class.

Comment: Oh, missed the static.

Comment: There's a free Visual Studio plugin available that will translate C# to VB.NET and back.

Comment: These automatic translations can only handle simple code parts, they didn't work here, I've tried several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. It's not explaining the error messages, but at least it's compiling and hopefully working afterwards.

I just added this to the class itself:

```
Private Sub OnValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ValueChanged(sender, e)
End Sub
```

And then instead of raising the event myself in the function `OnPropertyChanged`, I call my new procedure:

```
Private Shared Sub OnPropertyChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim notifier As PropertyChangeNotifier

    notifier = TryCast(d, PropertyChangeNotifier)
    If (notifier Is Nothing) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    notifier.OnValueChanged(notifier, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

Comment: You did not post this details in your question.

Comment: self answer related to source that was not posted and not mentioned in main question.

Answer (score -1):

```
  Private Shared Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
      Dim notifier As PropertyChangeNotifier = CType(d, PropertyChangeNotifier)
      If notifier.ValueChanged IsNot Nothing Then RaiseEvent notifier.ValueChanged(notifier, EventArgs.Empty)
  End Sub
```

Comment: Both `notifier.ValueChanged` tell me that it's an event and can't be called directly.

Comment: Public Event ValueChanged As EventHandler' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

Comment: The `notifier.ValueChanged` in the if-statemant will already throw that error